# Geoserver 2.16 cluster using amq 7.1. Can send messages to amq and see I am connected, but not receiving messages

Tags: amqp, geoserver

So I have 2 geoserver clusters. Ones version 2.15 (map01 and map02) and ones version 2.16 (map 03 and map04). All shows connected to amq upon startup (port 61616).

I can add a workspace on map01 (cluster A) and see if become available on map02, but not map 03 or map04 (cluster B).

If I add a workspace to map03 or map 04, I see it automatically populate on map 01 and map02. So something is stopping map 03 and map04 from getting those messages back. Thoughts on what I should look at?

I do not see any errors in the logs. On the geoserver side, my cluster.properties has:

```
toggleSlave=true
topicName=VirtualTopic.GeoServer
connection=enabled
brokerURL=tcp\://amq-server\:61616
durable=true
xbeanURL=./broker.xml
toggleMaster=true
embeddedBroker=disabled
CLUSTER_CONFIG_DIR=/opt/geoserver/cluster/
embeddedBrokerProperties=embedded-broker.properties
connection.retry=10
instanceName=map01.server.test
readOnly=disabled
group=geoserver-cluster
connection.maxwait=500
```

All servers have the same cluster config with the instanceName being different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I have figured out the underlying issue. It appears that having the InstanceName with "." in it was causing it to send messages to to VirtualTopic.Geoserver but was becoming a consumer to server.test.Virtualtopic.Geoserver. Once I modified the instancename to not have "." (changed to "-")...everything started working correctly.